# Example of infinite perfect field with char $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

All finite fields (they have char $p$ for some $p$ prime) are perfect. A well known field which is not finite and not perfect with char $p$ is $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, the field of rational functions with values in $\mathbb{F}_p$ with an unknown $t$.

> Can someone show me an example of perfect, infinite field with char $p$?

Answer (score 4):

A trivial example is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p(t)$.

Comment: Or more generally every algebraically closed field.

Comment: Well.. yes of course it follows by definition. But "what kind of elements are there"? And how to find any other non-trivial example?

Comment: @Gabrielek how about algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$? It is perfect and you can describe all its elements.

Comment: @Paul K $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed over $\mathbb{R}$ but it has char $0$

Comment: $\bigcup_n \Bbb{F}_p(t^{1/p^n})$ is easier to visualize

Comment: @Slup I'm pretty new to abstract algebra and I can't get them (I can't even see it is not finite). Can you tell me more details please?